what is the best way to reset Node's global variable for each test?
I have some Jest tests that only pass after another test run before it. When I look at the global variable I can see it is retaining values between tests which seems to be impacting the suite. I cannot find any documentation around best practices regarding managing the global variable (sometimes called window or globalThis).
I have seen some examples of the following in my code base:
const globalAny = global;

beforeEach(() => {
    globalAny.window = Object.create(global);
});

afterEach(() => {
    globalAny.window = globalAny;
});

This appears to work but I wonder if this is the best approach? Seems surprising there isn't more information about this (maybe Im searching the wrong search terms).

Asking for the "best" way drives the question into opinionated zone, and opinion-based questions aren't suitable on SO. There's no best way in general. The preferable solution depends on your case. For a known set of vars you can just list them explicitly. It can be done in general the way you did. Or the way suggested in the answer. Because there's no best way. It wouldn't hurt to cover this in the docs, but generally speaking, mocking any thing that persists through test suite includes backing it up in beforeEach and restoring it in afterEach, global vars are a special case of this

Also notice that In Jest dom setup global.window is the same as global (I don't remember if it's ===), and this approach breaks this. Doing this with window doesn't affect other global vars. E.g. location, which is more often accessed directly rather than window.location.

The approach is generally valid, though I would also consider using "setupFilesAfterEnv" property.
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array
And I also usually do the following in that file:
// jest.setup.js
beforeEach(() => {
    // Reset `window` to an empty object before each test to ensure isolation
    global.window = {};
});

afterEach(() => {
    // Clean up after each test
    delete global.window;
});


This will work, but this breaks Jest's setup where global is the same as global.window. This won't affect other global vars that aren't referred as window properties
